# Failed to start Journal Service ( Ubuntu 22.04 )

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

I have a dual booted system ( Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 ). I Installed ubuntu recently and it was working fine until yesterday. It is now stuck on a black screen with few error messages and the last one being " Failed to start Journal Service."

Comment: Please list ALL the error messages.

Comment: Did you find a reliable solution?